# How to display an image in webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I need to display an image in the column of a webgrid. Webgrid is filled using the list returned from the controller.I used the below code in view and controller respectively:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post ))
{

<div id ="DivGrid">
    @{
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model);
        @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "DataTable" }, columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(format: @<img src="@Href("vPath")"/>),
        grid.Column("title","Product Name"),
        grid.Column("user_ID","User ID"),
        grid.Column("", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditOrder", "OrderStatus", new { id = item.ID})</text>)));
      //  grid.Column("", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteOrder", "OrderStatus", new { id = item.ID}, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this Order status?');" })</text>)));          
        }

</div>



using (APM context = new APM())
            {
                lstorder = (from s in context.T_Order
                            join p in context.T_OrderDetails on s.ID equals p.Order_ID
                            join t in context.T_OrderDetailSpecification on p.ID equals t.OrderDetails_ID

                            join r in context.M_Product on p.Product_ID equals r.ID
                            where  s.OrderStatus_ID == 1 && p.IsPreviewRequired == 1 && p.OrderStatus_ID == 1

                            select new orderList
                            {
                                ID = p.ID,
                                vPath = r.VirtualPath,
                                product_ID = r.ID,
                                title = r.Title,
                                amount = t.Value,
                                user_ID= (int)s.User_ID,
                                sel_ID= (int)p.SelectionList_ID

                            }).ToList();

 return View(lstorder);
            }
```

But the code '`grid.Column(format: @<img src="@Href("vPath")"/>),`' not displaying the image .it simply showing the path something like /views/PreviewRequest/vPath

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

I changed

```
grid.Column(format: @<img src="@Href("vPath")"/>)
```

to

```
grid.Column(format: @<img src="@Href(item.vPath)"/>),
```